# enable scroll when MUI modal is active React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have quite a simple component using `MUI Modal`

```
const Contact = ({ open, handleClose }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <Box sx={contactModalStyle}>
            <div className='Contact'>
              <h2>contact today</h2>
            </div>
          </Box>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

When the modal is active the scrolling of the page is disabled by default, does MUI provide any props to enable scrolling of the page while the Modal is active? Assuming the page has the height dimensions required to continue scrolling vertically while the modal is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable `disableScrollLock` prop of the modal

```
<Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose} disableScrollLock>
  // ...
</Modal>
```

Demo

[image: Edit BasicModal Material Demo (forked)]